# How to create new dictionary from string?

Tags: python

I have a string: `my_str = "abra cadabra"`
I need to create a new dictionary , the keys in the dictionary are the letters in my_str and the value should be the amount of every letter.
For example:

```
my_str = "abra cadabra"
output >>
{'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'r': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

What i got is - `{'a': 5, 'b': 5, 'r': 5, 'c': 5, 'd': 5}`

Comment: what's your code? I can produce that output with `output = {k: 5 for k in set(my_str) if k.strip()}` -- but that seems wrong :D

Comment: There's a built-in `collections.Counter` function for this.

Comment: @Barmar just a quick correction Counter an object not a function right?

Comment: Yes, but you can use it like a function, just as you use `range()` like a function.

Comment: @Jab I mean most of the "functions" on the official documentation's [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) page aren't technically functions either.

Comment: ty i got it now !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_str = "abra cadabra"
my_set = set(my_str)
my_set.discard(" ")
my_dict = {}
for key in my_set:
    my_dict[key] = my_str.count(key)
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) could be used for this.

Example:

```
from collections import Counter

my_str = "abra cadabra"
my_str = my_str.replace(" ", "")

c = Counter(list(my_str))

print('{}\n{}\n{}'.format(c, c.keys(), c.values()))
```

output:

```
Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'r': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd'])
dict_values([5, 2, 2, 1, 1])
```

You can iterate through the keys and values just like you would a normal dict.